# Count edit distance

Tags: c, interview-questions

I have implemented a C code in order to answer an interview question. I would be appreciated if someone  would improve the code. Task is an easy, however I want to achieve best efficiency in terms of readability and simplicity. Pardon my English again.

- Sorry that I have just printed out the result.

> The edit distance between two strings refers to the minimum number of
> character insertions, deletions, and substitutions required to change
> one string to the other. For example, the edit distance between
> “kitten” and “sitting” is three: substitute the “k” for “s”,
> substitute the “e” for “i”, and append a “g”.
>
> Given two strings, compute the edit distance between them.

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int count_edit_dist(const char list1[],
    const char list2[])
{
    unsigned int count=0;
    size_t len_str1 = strlen(list1);
    size_t len_str2 = strlen(list2);


    for(int i=0; list1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(list2[i]=='\0') //means len(list2) < len(list1)
        {
            count += (unsigned int)(len_str1 - len_str2);
            return count;
        }

        if(list1[i] != list2[i])
            count++;
    }

    //reacing here means len(list1) <= len(list2)
    count += (unsigned int)(len_str2 - len_str1);
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int count;
    char list1[] = "category";
    char list2[] = "caterirrrr";

    count = count_edit_dist(list1, list2);
    printf("edit distance between strings: %u\n", count);
}
```

Comment: the program gives edit distance as 7 b/w 'sunday' and 'saturday'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Minimum edit distance**

`count_edit_dist()` does return a value, yet it is certainly not the *minimum* possible edit distance as defined.  To compute the minimum, a fair amount more code is needed.

---

Small stuff

**`unsigned` vs. `size_t` vs. `int`**

For practical uses, makes no difference, yet code would avoid casting by using `size_t` and making the `printf()` format strings agree.  `size_t` also correctly handles extreme cases.

```
// unsigned int count=0;
size_t count=0;
```

`size_t` is the best full range type for array indexing:

```
// for(int i=0; list1[i]!='\0'; i++)
for(size_t i=0; list1[i]!='\0'; i++)
```

**Declare when needed**

Instead of defining variables far from their first use ...

> ```
> unsigned int count;
> ...
> count = count_edit_dist(list1, list2);
> ```

... consider defining when needed:

```
...
unsigned int count = count_edit_dist(list1, list2);
```

**Spell check**

Run spell checker.

```
//   vv 
//reacing here means len(list1) <= len(list2)
//reaching
```

**Consider a more informative output**

```
printf("Edit distance between strings \"%s\" and \"%s\": %u\n", list1, list2, count);
```

**Testing with some form of `!`**

I find alternatives that avoid a form of negation easier to follow.  Yet this is a style issue - best to code to your group's style guide.

```
// for(int i=0; list1[i]!='\0'; i++)
for (int i=0; list1[i]; i++)
```

---

- Good formatting
- Good use of `const` in `unsigned int count_edit_dist(const char list1[], const char list2[])`
- Style: I'd use `unsigned` rather than `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

Running `strlen()` at the beginning is unecessary and can be replaced with a simpler `while` loop.

```
// A,B  are strings
unsigned int count_edit_dist(const char *A, const char *B)
{
    unsigned count=0;
    // a,b are pointers to current letters of A,B
    const char *a = A;
    const char *b = B;
    // while we have characters from either
    while (*a||*b) {
        // add to count i different
        if (*a!=*b) ++count;
        // increment letter if not at end of string
        if (*a) ++a;
        if (*b) ++b;
    }
    return count;
}
```